# Group by just day in a date_time column and take the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df like the df shown in the figures and I want to:

1. group by days of several years (2006 to 2010, example: group(2006-01-01, 2007-01-01, 2008-01-01, 2009-01-01, 20010-01-01)) and then,
2. take the mean value of the Pressure column of these days (2006-01-01, 2007-01-01, 2008-01-01, 2009-01-01, 20010-01-01) and then,
3. generate a new column with just the mean of the Pressure values

[image: df]
[image: df (continuation)]

Comment: Please share the sample of input and required output in text format.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the expected output, as well as your attempt at a solution.  You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67327226/edit) the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we need the original number of rows of data grouped by month and day, which can be achieved by creating and adding columns using the transform function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20210430)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('2006-01-01','2011-01-01', freq='1d')), 'Pressure':np.random.randint(40,60,(1827,))})

# Check the numbers beforehand.
df[(df.Date.dt.month == 1) & (df.Date.dt.day == 1)]

    Date    Pressure
0       2006-01-01  51
365     2007-01-01  45
730     2008-01-01  53
1096    2009-01-01  45
1461    2010-01-01  59
1826    2011-01-01  40

df['mean'] = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, df.Date.dt.day])['Pressure'].transform('mean')

# Numerical verification after the fact
df[(df.Date.dt.month == 1) & (df.Date.dt.day == 1)]

    Date    Pressure    mean
0       2006-01-01  51  48.833333
365     2007-01-01  45  48.833333
730     2008-01-01  53  48.833333
1096    2009-01-01  45  48.833333
1461    2010-01-01  59  48.833333
1826    2011-01-01  40  48.833333
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer